# C++ function error

Tags: c++

So with this assignment, I need to ask for judges scores and calculate the average. Haven't got to the calculation part, but I've done all the get score functions. Everything seems good, it compiles, but it never outputs the first cout when I test, it gives me a breakpoint at the first cout and I'm not sure why. Using Xcode by the way if that matters. Also, am I supposed to be using pass by reference or does the "return score1;" fulfill that purpose?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void getJudgeData(double&);

int main()
{
    double  score1, score2, score3, score4, score5;

    getJudgeData(score1);
    getJudgeData(score2);
    getJudgeData(score3);
    getJudgeData(score4);
    getJudgeData(score5);

 return 0;
}

void getJudgeData(double& score)
{
    cout << "Submit your score: ";
    cin >> score;

    while (score < 0.0 || score > 10.0)
    {
        cout << "Please re-enter a score between 0 - 10" << endl;
        cin >> score;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have five functions that do exactly the same thing?

Comment: `return score1;` works but where are you storing the value returned??

Comment: Please learn to use arrays.  What if instead of judges, a poll of 1,000 people were done.  You would create 1,000 different functions for each person that do exactly the same thing?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie we haven't learned them yet, so I definitely can't use them.

Comment: Based on your edit, it looks like you have fixed your problem, presumably with help from one or more of the answers below. You should upvote the answers the helped, and accept the answer that was most helpful. You should **not** edit your question to eliminate the code that was giving you trouble, because it makes this Q&A less useful for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually reading anything from the function.

Suggested alternative:

```
double getJudgeData()
{
    double score
    cout << "Submit your score:";
    cin >> score;

    while (score < 0.0 || score > 10.0)
    {
        cout << "Please re-enter a score between 0 - 10" << endl;
        cin >> score;
    }
    return score;
}

int main()
{
    double score1, score2, score3, score4, score5;
    double highest, lowest;

    score1 = getJudgeData();
    score2 = getJudgeData();
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to see the outputs when compiling with g++.  One thing you could try is using a flush after your cout (i.e. cout << "Submit your score:" << flush;).  If that doesn't work, my best guess would be that your output is being filtered or perhaps you aren't looking for the output in the correct view.  Check that you have 'All Output' selected in the debugger panel.

Oh and regarding the second part of your question, the double's that you're passing to the function are by value.  As paulsm4 highlighted, you can replace them with a local variable and return that instead.  If you wanted to pass them by reference, you'd have to use the address-of operator:

```
double getJudgeData(double& score);
```

Comment: Yea it works for me in cpp.sh, but not on Xcode. it gives me this "(lldb)"

Answer (score 1):

> am I supposed to be using pass by reference?

In this code, I think you will be better off using pass-by-reference.

These invocations do not match your declarations.

```
getJudgeData1(score1);
getJudgeData2(score2);
getJudgeData3(score3);
...
```

Your declarations need the reference in the formal parameter, as in:

```
// ------------------------v
double getJudgeData1(double& score1);
double getJudgeData2(double& score2);
double getJudgeData3(double& score3);
...
```

and now, you no longer need to return a value:

```
void getJudgeData1(double& score1);
void getJudgeData2(double& score2);
void getJudgeData3(double& score3);
...
```

And if you can recall the difference be formal parameters and actual parameters, you only need the one getJudgeData(...) function.

Good luck

Comment: I edited the original post. So for the first function, I'm calling it with score1, and it sends it in. But I'm using score as a double, with the & sign, it sends score back and replaces score1 with that value. Is that correct?

Comment: @HOAX - there's absolutely *NO NEED* to "pass by reference" unless you're both reading AND writing the variable inside of the function. In this case, you're not. You just want to get a value. So the easiest/cleanest/most efficient approach is to treat your function *AS* a function ... and simply return the "double". To answer your question: Yes, "return score1;" fulfills that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You should change two things.

1. Change function declaration and use pass by reference. double getJudgeData1(double& score1)
2. You should std::cout to output to console. 
   `cout<<score1<<score2;`

Comment: I edited the original post. So for the first function, I'm calling it with score1, and it sends it in. But I'm using score as a double, with the & sign, it sends score back and replaces score1 with that value. Is that correct?

Comment: yes thats correct change. If you want to just output those values to console use std::cout in int main() function. But if you want to calculate something using these values you can do that as well. Pass by reference basically reflect anything that happens inside the function. In your case inside getJudgeData1().